# Prevent Vim from indenting line when typing a colon (:) in Python

Tags: python, vim, vi

Whenever I append a `:` character in Vim in Python mode, it either:

- indents the line
- dedents the line
- does nothing

What is it even trying to do, and how do I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Why do you think it might be trying to indent a line? As in, a `:` character is used to denote a function or a control statement...

Comment: What kind of behavior do you really want?

Comment: This happened to me, but I accidentally switched from German to US keyboard in Ubuntu.

Comment: @YXD They're also used to associate dict keys with values, but in none of those cases would I want it to indent the current line (i.e., the line with the colon).

Comment: What if you have a URL in your data structure? It is a string that contains a colon. That also breaks indentation which is already set.

Comment: This is frustraing while you are typing a string that has a colon, or a dictionary definition, or walrus assignment, and it suddenly start going wonky.

Answer (score 38):

Certain keys, when pressed, will trigger Vim's indent feature, which will attempt to set the correct amount of indentation on the current line. (You can manually trigger this by typing `==` in normal mode.)

You can change which keys trigger this behavior, but first you need to know what indenting mode is being used.

First, execute `:set indentexpr?`. If it is nonempty (I would expect this for Python), then `indentexpr` mode is being used.  In this case, executing `:set indentkeys?` gives you the list of trigger keys. To remove the colon, execute `:setlocal indentkeys-=:`.

If `indentexpr` is empty, then you are probably using `cindent` mode, and `:set cindent?` will tell you that `cindent` is set. In this case, do the same as before, but using `cinkeys` instead of `indentkeys`. (Note that `indentexpr` mode takes precedence over `cindent` mode.)

Comment: But this won't persist across sessions, and adding to `.vimrc` won't help either, because the custom settings for Python are loaded afterwards.

Comment: Try putting it in .vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim

Comment: For me, editing a python file, `:set indentkeys?` showed `indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except`. See how the colon is specified, inside greater-than and less-than characters `<:>`. To get this to work in my case I had to do this: `:setlocal indentkeys-=<:>`.

Comment: Also see [`:h indentkeys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentkeys%27), [`:h indentkeys-format`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#indentkeys-format), and [`:h key-notation`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation). (Those are all links to the online vim documentation)

Comment: Thank you @ChristianLong, the key-notation doc showed the diff between `<:>` and `:`.

Answer (score 26):

[Nathan Grigg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820207/456550) set me on the right track. I had to make a few changes for my setup.

I had to use `:setlocal indentkeys-=<:>`, because in my case `:set indentkeys?` showed `indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except`.

Also, putting `:setlocal indentkeys-=<:>` in `.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` did not work to make the change permanent. I found that there is a built-in vim python indent file that runs AFTER this after-ftplugin file.

To diagnose, open a Python file for editing, and run `:scriptnames`. That will show you a list of all the vim scripts that have run, in order of precedence. The scripts at the bottom of that list have been applied most recently, and take precedence. See [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/166902/why-does-vim-ignore-files-in-vim-after-ftplugin) for more info.

When I did that, it showed me a built-in vim file at `/my-install-path/vim/7.4.1830/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim`. Sure enough, that was setting `<:>` as part of the indent keys.

To fix it, I set an autocommand in .vimrc, and that really gets the last word.

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal indentkeys-=<:>
```

**Update**

I had to add `:setlocal indentkeys-=:` after all. Here's what I have in my `.vimrc` now.

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal indentkeys-=<:>
autocmd FileType python setlocal indentkeys-=:
```

Comment: I only needed the `<:>` line to undo the setting in python-mode plugin.  the second line in your update means something else must be turning on `:` as an indentkeys

Comment: Did you try `.vim/after/indent/python.vim` though?

Answer (score 7):

It is trying to be helpful. If you want to turn off all the auto-indenting for the current file,

```
:setlocal noautoindent
:setlocal nocindent
:setlocal nosmartindent
:setlocal indentexpr=
```

Or, you can add set in your vimrc file. You can do these per file type too. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting)

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR* I disabled autoindentation by typing:

> **:set indentexpr=**

then hitting the ENTER key.

It's a quick fix without needing to understand *indentkeys* ..

Thanks to [Christian Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456550/christian-long) for the docs to [indentkeys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentkeys%27), where I noticed (my emphasis):

> A list of keys that, when typed in Insert mode, cause reindenting of
>       the current line.  *Only happens if 'indentexpr' isn't empty*.

Tip - you might want to save a copy of the existing value of *indentexpr* before you clear it out. To see that (and any other values that are set) just type:

> :set

HTH